# "fdw_redis" scan all Redis records instead single query

Tags: postgresql, redis, postgresql-9.6

I have a problem with transforming information via Redis->Postgresql 9.6

I'm using extension [fdw_redis](https://github.com/pg-redis-fdw/redis_fdw) with hiredis and I created FOREIGN TABLE redis_db0_ch.

When I make simple query

```
select "key", value from redis_db0_ch where "key"='Ch_152';
```

using "cli-redis monitor" I saw that it was OK: single qual to Redis for 1 sql-query

> "ZRANGE" "Ch_152" "0" "-1"

but when I wrapped sql-query into Function with input param:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "SMSCEngine".f_get_redis_test(input_param integer)
RETURNS TABLE(_key text, _value text)
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
begin
return query 
    select "key", value from redis_db0_ch where "key"='Ch_' || input_param;
end;
$function$
```

sql-query become:

```
select * from "SMSCEngine".f_get_redis_test(152);
```

Result in "cli-redis monitor" was overhelmed: 5 times it was ok, but then it started to scan all redis records, ignoring my filter (where "key"='Ch_')

> "ZRANGE" "Ch_152" "0" "-1" //5 times
>
> "SCAN" "0" "MATCH" "Ch_*" "COUNT" "1000" //from 6 times

As a result - reducing performance.
I guess it is optimization method in postgres or extension.
How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like the result of [PL/pgSQL plan caching](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-implementation.html#PLPGSQL-PLAN-CACHING). You're right, it's supposed to be an optimisation technique, but as you can see, it occasionally makes some pretty questionable decisions.

In general, you can suppress this behaviour by running your query via `EXECUTE`, which will force PL/pgSQL to re-plan it every time:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "SMSCEngine".f_get_redis_test(input_param integer)
RETURNS TABLE(_key text, _value text)
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
begin
return query
    execute 'select "key", value from redis_db0_ch where "key" = $1'
    using 'Ch_' || input_param;
end;
$function$
```

However, if your function is just a single query, there is probably no need for PL/pgSQL at all; you can write it in `LANGUAGE sql`, which as far as I know, doesn't have this problem:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "SMSCEngine".f_get_redis_test(input_param integer)
RETURNS TABLE(_key text, _value text)
LANGUAGE sql
AS $function$
  select "key", value from redis_db0_ch where "key" = 'Ch_' || input_param
$function$
```